# What is this myth about Helios?

Tags: greek, myth-identification

Well, there was a guy who wanted to get on the sun chariot, but eventually he died or something happened to him, but he got too close or something. What is the name of the boy, and what is the time period?

Comment: You are confusing Helios, the original Titan Greek sun god https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios, with Phaethon, the son of Apollo (or maybe Helios) who insisted on driving the sun's chariot and couldn't control the horses so the earth burned and froze until Zeus killed him with a thunderbolt. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaethon

Comment: No, I was asking about Phaethon. If you put that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing [Helios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios), the original Titan Greek sun god, with [Phaethon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaethon), the son of Apollo (or maybe Helios) who insisted on driving the sun's chariot and couldn't control the horses so the earth burned and froze until Zeus killed him with a thunderbolt.

Answer (score 2):

Phaethon was the [son of Helios](http://www.theoi.com/Titan/Phaethon.html), definitely not Apollo. For a long time his mother, Klymene, wouldn't tell him who his father was, but he finally talked her into it after being mocked by his friends.

He went to Helios and demanded his father acknowledge him in a public gesture. When Phaethon asked to drive the sun chariot, his father was stuck, and had to let him. And finally, Zeus had to kill him with a thunderbolt.

In some versions, Phaethon became the [constellation Auriga](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tyj8UUE968wC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=Auriga%20Phaethon&source=bl&ots=N50hD7L2WR&sig=rDmFjbKLy8ne5woqfNa8i88wngI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFrfL6lJ7KAhULXD4KHYCbBg0Q6AEIQTAH#v=onepage&q=Auriga%20Phaethon&f=false), the Charioteer. Others ([Ovid in particular](http://ovid.lib.virginia.edu/trans/Metamorph2.htm)) said that after his burned body fell into the river Eridanus, his sisters turned into poplar trees, weeping over the river and his grave.